# NSDateComponents setTimeZone NSInvalidArgumentException at iOS 3.1

Tags: iphone, nsdatecomponents

[NSDateComponents setTimeZone:] function crashes at iOS 3.1, gives NSInvalidArgumentException. but it works fine at higher iOS versions. Is there anyone who has a solution for this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This method is (publicly) available starting 4.0 OS only so you must not call that method on 3.x OS - perform run-time check if NSDateComponent instance responds to selector before calling it:

```
NSDateComponents* comps = ...;
if ([comps respondsToSelector:@selector(setTimeZone:)])
    [comps setTimeZone:zone];
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. what else can i use for setting time zone?i need this because if i dont set the time zone to UTC app adds current time zone's interval to the hours. for example, if the current time zone is GMT + 3 and NSDate's hour is 20:00, it becomes 23:00.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve that... There're several other places where you can set time zone - in NSDateFormatter for output, in NSCalendar, +setDefaultTimeZone in NSTimeZone - may be using some of them will serve your purpose

Comment: I set time zone at NSCalendar too but didn't solve. thanks anyway.